# PrimeNG Tree expanded Icon not showing

Tags: primeng

I have an Angular 13.1.0 project with PrimeNG 13.0.2
I'm trying to use the Tree component to paint a tree with parents and childs, my problem is with the "expandedIcon" and "collapsedIcon" property.

The component simply ignore this values, and always painting the parent expandable node with the default icon "pi-chevron-right". Apart from this, the icon is showing always as a blank square.

My problem with the square icon will be solved if the node shows a Fontawesome icon, that i define on the "expandedIcon" and "collapsedIcon" property, but prime faces always try to use the default icon.

This is my parent node:

```
{
    "label": "Page Info",
    "type": "PAGE_NODE",
    "expandedIcon": "fas fa-chevron-up",
    "collapsedIcon": "fas fa-chevron-down"
}
```

And PrimeNG draw it like this:

[image]

Update:
I have see the source code of PrimeNG, and the icon is on the code, without any option to change it:

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/13.0.4/src/app/components/tree/tree.ts

```
<button type="button" [attr.aria-label]="tree.togglerAriaLabel" class="p-tree-toggler p-link" (click)="toggle($event)" pRipple tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="p-tree-toggler-icon pi pi-fw" [ngClass]="{'pi-chevron-right':!node.expanded,'pi-chevron-down':node.expanded}"></span>
                    </button>
```